# How can I get base 64 or binary data from pdf after adding annotations?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe, mozilla

I am using mozilla pdf js viewer. Initially I am showing  my base 64 string into my page through the iframe.

```
const base64 = 'JVBERi0xLjMNJcjIyMjIyMgNMSAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvT3V0bGluZXMgMiAwIFIvUGFnZXMgMyAwIFIvTWV0YWRhdGEgMTEgMCBSPj4NCmVuZG9iagoyIDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUvT3V0bGluZXMvQ291bnQgMD4+DQplbmRvYmoKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlL1BhZ2VzL0NvdW50IDIvS2lkc1s0IDAgUiA2IDAgUl0+Pg0KZW5kb2JqCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZS9QYWdlL1BhcmVudCAzIDAgUi9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250PDwvRjEgOSAwIFI+Pi9Qcm9jU2V0IDggMCBSPj4vTWVkaWFCb3hbMCAwIDYxMiA3OTJdL0NvbnRlbnRzIDUgMCBSL0Fubm90c1sxNiAwIFIgMTcgMCBSIDE4IDAgUiAxOSAwIFJdPj4NCmVuZG9iago1IDAgb2JqCjw8L0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMzAyPj5zdHJlYW0NCnicvVPRSsMwFH3PV5xHBb22WdOmj5tuD8JAsfge1nTLaNPZpCJ+va3bXgZmE8EkcHMezjncc7nsjXE8slnBIoy3W7O7RQyeoaiYyGiSCWScE5coSnaFKV5Ms6s1nh4WWJjhc41iy+bFKDEy42hkpjlxgVRKSqMDs9gYh+EpuEbVNUrdtNb5TnnTWtCurFCNerdBxTShLEr2itveeVRth95pGAu/0Xg1ne9VjaVebZQ1Kwff+7YzqnaEZdtpeP3hCVNbohlhyExwygTfm53QLoEhaS5JJsdMfyP6EwyZxSnJPA30MRsSsusbfI7nEsuQW5RQnhxG9Oe2ziYpck55zi9JMqQylEj+0zzEsFfxJDSPEzh/1/YbE+5b643tdYlhaXZqrcFBREe35y8iwhNSDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iago2IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUvUGFnZS9QYXJlbnQgMyAwIFIvUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udDw8L0YxIDkgMCBSPj4vUHJvY1NldCA4IDAgUj4+L01lZGlhQm94WzAgMCA2MTIgNzkyXS9Db250ZW50cyA3IDAgUj4+DQplbmRvYmoKNyAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggNjc2Pj5zdHJlYW0NCjIgSg0KQlQNCjAgMCAwIHJnDQovRjEgMDAyNyBUZg0KNTcuMzc1MCA3MjIuMjgwMCBUZA0KKCBTaW1wbGUgUERGIEZpbGUgMiApIFRqDQpFVA0KQlQNCi9GMSAwMDEwIFRmDQo2OS4yNTAwIDY4OC42MDgwIFRkDQooIC4uLmNvbnRpbnVlZCBmcm9tIHBhZ2UgMS4gWWV0IG1vcmUgdGV4dC4gQW5kIG1vcmUgdGV4dC4gQW5kIG1vcmUgdGV4dC4gKSBUag0KRVQNCkJUDQovRjEgMDAxMCBUZg0KNjkuMjUwMCA2NzYuNjU2MCBUZA0KKCBBbmQgbW9yZSB0ZXh0LiBBbmQgbW9yZSB0ZXh0LiBBbmQgbW9yZSB0ZXh0LiBBbmQgbW9yZSB0ZXh0LiBBbmQgbW9yZSApIFRqDQpFVA0KQlQNCi9GMSAwMDEwIFRmDQo2OS4yNTAwIDY2NC43MDQwIFRkDQooIHRleHQuIE9oLCBob3cgYm9yaW5nIHR5cGluZyB0aGlzIHN0dWZmLiBCdXQgbm90IGFzIGJvcmluZyBhcyB3YXRjaGluZyApIFRqDQpFVA0KQlQNCi9GMSAwMDEwIFRmDQo2OS4yNTAwIDY1Mi43NTIwIFRkDQooIHBhaW50IGRyeS4gQW5kIG1vcmUgdGV4dC4gQW5kIG1vcmUgdGV4dC4gQW5kIG1vcmUgdGV4dC4gQW5kIG1vcmUgdGV4dC4gKSBUag0KRVQNCkJUDQovRjEgMDAxMCBUZg0KNjkuMjUwMCA2NDAuODAwMCBUZA0KKCBCb3JpbmcuICBNb3JlLCBhIGxpdHRsZSBtb3JlIHRleHQuIFRoZSBlbmQsIGFuZCBqdXN0IGFzIHdlbGwuICkgVGoNCkVUDQoNCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqCjggMCBvYmoKWy9QREYvVGV4dF0NCmVuZG9iago5IDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUvRm9udC9TdWJ0eXBlL1R5cGUxL05hbWUvRjEvQmFzZUZvbnQvSGVsdmV0aWNhL0VuY29kaW5nL1dpbkFuc2lFbmNvZGluZz4+DQplbmRvYmoKMTAgMCBvYmoKPDwvQ3JlYXRvcihBc3Bvc2UgTHRkLikvUHJvZHVjZXIoQXNwb3NlLlBERiBmb3IgSmF2YSAyMC4zKS9DcmVhdGlvbkRhdGUoRDoyMDA2MDMwMTA3MjgyNikvTW9kRGF0ZShEOjIwMjMwMTE3MDkyMTA5KzAwJzAwJyk+Pg0KZW5kb2JqCjExIDAgb2JqCjw8L0xlbmd0aCA1NjAvVHlwZS9NZXRhZGF0YS9TdWJ0eXBlL1hNTD4+c3RyZWFtDQo8P3hwYWNrZXQgYmVnaW49Iu+7vyIgaWQ9Ilc1TTBNcENlaGlIenJlU3pOVGN6a2M5ZCI/Pgo8eDp4bXBtZXRhIHhtbG5zOng9ImFkb2JlOm5zOm1ldGEvIj4KIDxyZGY6UkRGIHhtbG5zOnJkZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS8wMi8yMi1yZGYtc3ludGF4LW5zIyI+CiAgPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIj4KICAgPHhtcDplY20tZG9jLWlkPjQyYzBhMmIzLTlmMzktNGM3YS1hYjc1LWFkNDU0NTBiN2NhMzwveG1wOmVjbS1kb2MtaWQ+CiAgIDx4bXA6ZWNtLWhvc3QtbmFtZT4zMTU3ZjViOGUxZGU8L3htcDplY20taG9zdC1uYW1lPgogICA8eG1wOmVjbS1jcmVhdGlvbi1kYXRlPjIwMjItMTItMjBUMTQ6NDY6MTIuNDM1WjwveG1wOmVjbS1jcmVhdGlvbi1kYXRlPgogICA8eG1wOmVjbS11c2VyLWlkPnhsaW5lLWFkbWluLXVzZXItZW52MTwveG1wOmVjbS11c2VyLWlkPgogIDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPgogPC9yZGY6UkRGPgo8L3g6eG1wbWV0YT4KPD94cGFja2V0IGVuZD0iciI/Pg0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoKMTIgMCBvYmoKPDwvUmVjdFs3Mi4wMyA2ODYuNTM4IDEzNS4zNyA2OTcuNTM4XS9UeXBlL0Fubm90L0YgNC9QIDQgMCBSL1F1YWRQb2ludHNbNzIuMDMgNjk3LjUzOCAxMzUuMzcgNjk3LjUzOCA3Mi4wMyA2ODYuNTM4IDEzNS4zNyA2ODYuNTM4XS9TdWJ0eXBlL0hpZ2hsaWdodC9BUDw8L04gMTMgMCBSPj4vUkMoVGhpcyBpcyBhIHNtYWxsKS9Db250ZW50cyhteSBhbm5vdGF0aW9uKS9UKHhsaW5lLWFkbWluLXVzZXItZW52MSkvQ1swLjQ5MDE5NjA3ODQzMTM3MyAwLjg3ODQzMTM3MjU0OTAyIDAuNDkwMTk2MDc4NDMxMzczXS9NKEQ6MjAyMjEyMjgxNTA2MTQrMDAnMDAnKT4+DQplbmRvYmoKMTMgMCBvYmoKPDwvRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL1N1YnR5cGUvRm9ybS9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3QvRm9ybVR5cGUgMS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9YT2JqZWN0PDw+Pi9Gb250PDwvSGVsdiAxNSAwIFI+Pi9Qcm9jU2V0IDE0IDAgUi9FeHRHU3RhdGU8PC9UcmFuc0dzPDwvVHlwZS9FeHRHU3RhdGUvQUlTIGZhbHNlL0JNL011bHRpcGx5L0NBIDEvY2EgMT4+Pj4+Pi9NYXRyaXhbMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL0JCb3hbMCAwIDYzLjM0IDExXS9MZW5ndGggODc+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJzjKuTSDylKzCt2L1ZIL+Yy0DOxNDC0NDMwtzAxNjQ2N1Yw0LOAso1MgXJGCphKitLJ0xfkzmWgYKCQCyQNDRVyuMyM9YxNkJkGQFYGlxNXIAC9nSJfDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iagoxNCAwIG9iagpbL1BERl0NCmVuZG9iagoxNSAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlL0ZvbnQvU3VidHlwZS9UeXBlMS9CYXNlRm9udC9IZWx2ZXRpY2EvTmFtZS9IZWx2Pj4NCmVuZG9iagoxNiAwIG9iago8PC9SZWN0Wzc5IDY2NSAyOTAgNjY4XS9UeXBlL0Fubm90L0YgNC9QIDQgMCBSL1N1YnR5cGUvU3F1YXJlL0NvbnRlbnRzKHRleHQgc2hhcGUpL1QoeGxpbmUtYWRtaW4tdXNlci1lbnYxKS9DWzAuOTI5NDExNzY0NzA1ODgyIDAuODY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY3IDAuMzI1NDkwMTk2MDc4NDMxXS9NKEQ6MjAyMzAxMTMxMDI0MDkrMDAnMDAnKS9CUzw8L1cgMz4+L0JFPDw+Pj4+DQplbmRvYmoKMTcgMCBvYmoKPDwvUmVjdFsxMTcgNjQ0IDEzMiA3NTZdL1R5cGUvQW5ub3QvRiA0L1AgNCAwIFIvU3VidHlwZS9Qb2x5TGluZS9Db250ZW50cyhuZXN0byBkcnVnbykvVCh4bGluZS1hZG1pbi11c2VyLWVudjEpL0NbMC4zMTc2NDcwNTg4MjM1MjkgMC4wOTQxMTc2NDcwNTg4MjM1IDAuMjg2Mjc0NTA5ODAzOTIyXS9NKEQ6MjAyMzAxMTMxMDE5MTIrMDAnMDAnKS9WZXJ0aWNlc1s1NC43MTk4Nzc2MjI4MTQ0IDE3Mi43MDk2MzcyMjcxMjcgNTUuMjg5ODc1Mzc0MjIyMiAxNzIuNzA5NjM3MjI3MTI3IDU2Ljk5OTg3MjA5MDk1MTcgMTczLjg0OTYzMjcyOTk0MyA1OC43MDk4NzIyNzAxODc0IDE3My44NDk2MzI3Mjk5NDMgNjcuMjU5ODUyMzkxMzI4OSAxNzYuMTI5NjM3NTg1NTk5IDc1LjIzOTgzNDc2MTA2MjYgMTc3LjI2OTYzMzA4ODQxNCA4MC45Mzk4MjYxMjUxNjUxIDE3Ny4yNjk2MzMwODg0MTQgOTIuOTA5NzkyNzU0NzUzNSAxNzguNDA5NjAwODkxMTgxIDk2Ljg5OTc5MDg2NDYzMjYgMTc4Ljk3OTU5ODY0MjU4OSA5OC4wMzk4MDAyMTc0NzI1IDE3OS41NDk1ODI1NDM5NzIgMTAxLjQ1OTc3OTgwMDkwNyAxODIuMzk5NjEyODUxMDg1IDEwMi4wMjk3Nzc1NTIzMTUgMTgyLjk2OTYxMDYwMjQ5MiAxMDIuNTk5Nzc1MzAzNzIzIDE4My41Mzk1OTQ1MDM4NzYgMTAzLjE2OTc3OTk4MDE0MyAxODQuMTA5NTkyMjU1Mjg0IDEwMy4xNjk3Nzk5ODAxNDMgMTg0LjY3OTU5MDAwNjY5MSAxMDYuMDE5NzY4NzM3MTgyIDE4OC4wOTk2MDQyMTUxODcgMTA2LjU4OTc2NjQ4ODU5IDE4OC42Njk1ODgxMTY1NyAxMTEuMTQ5NzYyMzQ5ODc3IDE5Mi4wODk1NzQ2MjUwMTcgMTExLjcxOTc1MzE3NjI3MiAxOTIuMDg5NTc0NjI1MDE3IDExMS43MTk3NTMxNzYyNzIgMTkyLjY1OTU4NjIyNjQ1IDExNS4xMzk3NDY2MDk3MzEgMTkzLjIyOTU4Mzk3Nzg1NyAxMTYuMjc5NzM1MTg3NTM1IDE5My4yMjk1ODM5Nzc4NTcgMTE2LjI3OTczNTE4NzUzNSAxOTMuMjI5NTgzOTc3ODU3IDExNi44NDk3MzI5Mzg5NDMgMTkzLjIyOTU4Mzk3Nzg1NyAxMTcuNDE5NzQ0NTQwMzc1IDE5My4yMjk1ODM5Nzc4NTcgMTIxLjQwOTcyODgwMDIyOSAxOTMuNzk5NTgxNzI5MjY1IDEyMS45Nzk3MjY1NTE2MzcgMTkzLjc5OTU4MTcyOTI2NSAxMjguMjQ5NzI5NTE3MTcyIDE5My43OTk1ODE3MjkyNjUgMTI5Ljk1OTcwODkyMTM3MSAxOTMuNzk5NTgxNzI5MjY1IDEzMS4wOTk3MTgyNzQyMTEgMTkzLjc5OTU4MTcyOTI2NSAxMzIuODA5NzExNTI4NDM0IDE5My43OTk1ODE3MjkyNjUgMTM0LjUxOTcwNDc4MjY1OCAxOTMuNzk5NTgxNzI5MjY1IDEzNi4yMjk2OTgwMzY4ODEgMTkzLjc5OTU4MTcyOTI2NSAxMzkuMDc5NzE0NDkzOTY5IDE5My43OTk1ODE3MjkyNjUgMTQxLjM1OTY5MTY0OTU3NiAxOTMuNzk5NTgxNzI5MjY1IDE0NS4zNDk2NzU5MDk0MzEgMTkyLjA4OTU3NDYyNTAxNyAxNDguMTk5Njc4NTE2NDk0IDE5Mi4wODk1NzQ2MjUwMTcgMTQ5LjkwOTY3MTc3MDcxNyAxOTAuOTQ5NTc5MTIyMjAyIDE1NS4wMzk2NTE1MzMzODggMTg2Ljk1OTU5NDg2MjM0NyAxNTUuNjA5NjYzMTM0ODIgMTg2LjM4OTU4MzI2MDkxNSAxNTkuNTk5NjMzNTQ0NjUgMTc0LjQxOTYzMDQ4MTM1MSAxNjQuNzI5NjI3MTU3MzQ1IDE3Ni42OTk2MzUzMzcwMDYgMTcyLjEzOTYzOTQ3NTcyIDE4MC42ODk2MDU3NDY4MzcgMTczLjg0OTYzMjcyOTk0MyAxODEuMjU5NjE3MzQ4MjY5IDE3NC40MTk2MzA0ODEzNTEgMTgxLjgyOTYxNTA5OTY3NyAxNzYuNjk5NjM1MzM3MDA2IDE4MS44Mjk2MTUwOTk2NzcgMTgxLjI1OTYxNzM0ODI2OSAxODMuNTM5NTk0NTAzODc2IDE4MS44Mjk2MTUwOTk2NzcgMTgzLjUzOTU5NDUwMzg3NiAxODIuOTY5NjEwNjAyNDkyIDE4My41Mzk1OTQ1MDM4NzYgMTg4LjA5OTYwNDIxNTE4NyAxODMuNTM5NTk0NTAzODc2IDE4OS44MDk1ODM2MTkzODYgMTgzLjUzOTU5NDUwMzg3NiAxOTEuNTE5NTkwNzIzNjM0IDE4My41Mzk1OTQ1MDM4NzYgMTk5LjQ5OTU1OTI0MzM0MyAxODMuNTM5NTk0NTAzODc2IDIwMS4yMDk1NjYzNDc1OTEgMTgzLjUzOTU5NDUwMzg3NiAyMDIuMzQ5NTYxODUwNDA3IDE4My41Mzk1OTQ1MDM4NzYgMjA0LjA1OTU1NTEwNDYzIDE4My41Mzk1OTQ1MDM4NzYgMjA4LjYxOTUzNzExNTg5MyAxODIuOTY5NjEwNjAyNDkyIDIwOC42MTk1MzcxMTU4OTMgMTgyLjk2OTYxMDYwMjQ5MiAyMDkuNzU5NTMyNjE4NzA4IDE4Mi4zOTk2MTI4NTEwODUgMjEwLjMyOTU0NDIyMDE0IDE4Mi4zOTk2MTI4NTEwODUgMjExLjQ2OTU1MzU3Mjk4IDE4Mi4zOTk2MTI4NTEwODUgMjEyLjAzOTUzNzQ3NDM2NCAxODIuMzk5NjEyODUxMDg1IDIxNi4wMjk1NDk0MzQyNjcgMTgyLjM5OTYxMjg1MTA4NSAyMTYuNTk5NTMzMzM1NjUxIDE4Mi4zOTk2MTI4NTEwODUgMjE3LjczOTUyODgzODQ2NiAxODIuMzk5NjEyODUxMDg1IDIxOC4zMDk1MjY1ODk4NzQgMTgxLjgyOTYxNTA5OTY3N10vQlM8PC9XIDM+Pi9CRTw8Pj4+Pg0KZW5kb2JqCjE4IDAgb2JqCjw8L1JlY3RbNzIuMDMgNjg2LjUzOCAxMzUuMzcgNjk3LjUzOF0vVHlwZS9Bbm5vdC9GIDQvUCA0IDAgUi9RdWFkUG9pbnRzWzcyLjAzIDY5Ny41MzggMTM1LjM3IDY5Ny41MzggNzIuMDMgNjg2LjUzOCAxMzUuMzcgNjg2LjUzOF0vU3VidHlwZS9TdHJpa2VPdXQvUkMoVGhpcyBpcyBhIHNtYWxsKS9Db250ZW50cyhteSBhbm5vdGF0aW9uKS9UKHhsaW5lLWFkbWluLXVzZXItZW52MSkvQ1swLjc4MDM5MjE1Njg2Mjc0NSAwIDAuMjIzNTI5NDExNzY0NzA2XS9NKEQ6MjAyMjEyMjgxNTIzMTcrMDAnMDAnKT4+DQplbmRvYmoKMTkgMCBvYmoKPDwvUmVjdFs4MSA2NjcgMjg4IDY2OF0vVHlwZS9Bbm5vdC9GIDQvUCA0IDAgUi9TdWJ0eXBlL1NxdWFyZS9Db250ZW50cygpL1QoeGxpbmUtYWRtaW4tdXNlci1lbnYxKS9DWzAuOTI5NDExNzY0NzA1ODgyIDAuODY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY3IDAuMzI1NDkwMTk2MDc4NDMxXS9NKEQ6MjAyMzAxMTcwOTIxMDUrMDAnMDAnKS9CUzw8L1cgMz4+L0JFPDw+Pj4+DQplbmRvYmoKeHJlZgowIDIwDQowMDAwMDAwMDAwIDY1NTM1IGYNCjAwMDAwMDAwMTggMDAwMDAgbg0KMDAwMDAwMDA5NSAwMDAwMCBuDQowMDAwMDAwMTM4IDAwMDAwIG4NCjAwMDAwMDAxOTYgMDAwMDAgbg0KMDAwMDAwMDM1OSAwMDAwMCBuDQowMDAwMDAwNzMxIDAwMDAwIG4NCjAwMDAwMDA4NTggMDAwMDAgbg0KMDAwMDAwMTU4NSAwMDAwMCBuDQowMDAwMDAxNjEzIDAwMDAwIG4NCjAwMDAwMDE3MTAgMDAwMDAgbg0KMDAwMDAwMTg1MiAwMDAwMCBuDQowMDAwMDAyNDkwIDAwMDAwIG4NCjAwMDAwMDI4MjYgMDAwMDAgbg0KMDAwMDAwMzE5NCAwMDAwMCBuDQowMDAwMDAzMjE4IDAwMDAwIG4NCjAwMDAwMDMyOTMgMDAwMDAgbg0KMDAwMDAwMzUyMiAwMDAwMCBuDQowMDAwMDA2MDAxIDAwMDAwIG4NCjAwMDAwMDYzMDYgMDAwMDAgbg0KdHJhaWxlcgo8PC9Sb290IDEgMCBSL0luZm8gMTAgMCBSL0lEWzwzMDMyMkQzODQ0MkQ0NjMxMkQzMDM4MkQzNzM4MkQ0ND48NDE0NTJENDU0MzJEMzUzNjJEMzEzMzJEMzEzMjJEMzQ+XS9TaXplIDIwPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjY1MjUKJSVFT0YK'

function base64ToBlob(base64, type = "application/octet-stream") {
    const binStr = atob(base64);
    const len = binStr.length;
    const arr = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([arr], { type: type });
}
const blob = base64ToBlob(base64, 'application/pdf');
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var url = "/web/viewer.html?file=" + blobUrl;
var iframe = document.getElementById('pdf-viewer');
iframe.src = url;
iframe.addEventListener("load", function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let PDFViewerApplication = window.iframe.contentWindow.PDFViewerApplication;
        console.log('PDFViewerApplication', PDFViewerApplication);
    })
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>'Hello, world!' example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="pdf-viewer"></iframe>
<button class="download-btn">Download</button>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

after I load the pdf I have option to add some other annotations for example free text feature or self drawing

[image]

but I can't find a way to access to the reference of this file, and transform it to base 64.
So after the user makes all of the modifications I will get base 64 with all annotations in my pdf
old and new ones.

I can't find such an example for that.

I access to the pdf viewer reference through the `PDFViewerApplication` property. I have such a variable and there are a bunch of properties and methods availvable from pdf js viewer library.

How can i get base 64 with all of the annotations or binary format ?

Answer (score 1):

I investigated through the source code of the viewer js library and there is save method which will save the document together with annotations.
I am using some of the internal methods of this library to get instance to the pdf file, get it's binary data and afterwards convert it to base64

```
let binary;
async function save() {
    let PDFViewerApplication = window.iframe.contentWindow.PDFViewerApplication;
    if (PDFViewerApplication._saveInProgress) {
      return;
    }
    PDFViewerApplication._saveInProgress = true;
    await PDFViewerApplication.pdfScriptingManager.dispatchWillSave();
    const url = PDFViewerApplication._downloadUrl,
      filename = PDFViewerApplication._docFilename;
    try {
      PDFViewerApplication._ensureDownloadComplete();
      const data = await PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.saveDocument();
      console.log('save binary', data);
      const blob = new Blob([data], {
        type: "application/pdf"
      });
      binary = data;
      convertBinaryToBase64(data);
    //   await PDFViewerApplication.downloadManager.download(blob, url, filename);
    } catch (reason) {
      console.error(`Error when saving the document: ${reason.message}`);
      await PDFViewerApplication.download();
    } finally {
      await PDFViewerApplication.pdfScriptingManager.dispatchDidSave();
      PDFViewerApplication._saveInProgress = false;
      console.log('finally', binary);
    }
    if (PDFViewerApplication._hasAnnotationEditors) {
      PDFViewerApplication.externalServices.reportTelemetry({
        type: "editing",
        data: {
          type: "save"
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no problem here. This is how Adobe PDF use pdf field annotation to send information back to the mother server (via a submit mail button) in Acroforms, but has fallen in terms of usage as insecure and unwieldy, except some government/organisational forms that **insist you use Acrobat Reader** to control the upload of the altered data.

- YOU (as a user) make alterations to a PDF downloaded by the html instructions, to add text or lines in a browser PDF binary extension, like Acrobat Reader or SumatraPDF Plugin or Chrome (Foxit) or FireFox (Mozilla PDF.js). They all do roughly the same with one or two odd differences. E.G. thy all use different temporary storage filenames thus no common one.

[image: ![enter image description here]

- YOU save the annotation modifications, by renaming the file into a folder on the CPU (device) filesystem. (you can set that the same name if the user complies). See the filename above is only the temporary local name. So need rename to a drive:\folder\file.pdf
- You then run that OS (Systems Native) Base64 utility so for Windows users that's via certutil.exe. For Linux or Mac its supposedly base64 -e
- You then ask the user to upload their base64 file from their file system. (much easier to use a file picker for the NEW.PDF.

Comment: I do not need this approach

Comment: @K J Thank you for your time. I have webapp application where I show some pdfs. This pdf's are edited with some annotation. Right now we have approach where we have annotation service on BACKEND and we send the x and y coordinates of the annotations through the API.I don't understand what you recommend - what is another solution ?

Comment: Please be more specific

Answer (score -2):

To get binary data from a PDF file with annotations, you can use a PDF library or tool that allows programmatic manipulation of PDFs. Extract the binary data, add annotations, save and extract the data again. Check the library's documentation for specific methods.

Comment: Vague answer. Could you provide a code sample that works?